# How to get the real font name of a div on a web page when it set css font-family?

Tags: css, fonts

We can set web page font by using css `font-family`, when something goes wrong, I need to know the **exact** font name for each element. It may depends on system font or browser configuration, knowing the actual font will help to debug the case.

So if I'm using chrome under OSX, is there any way I can get the real font for a web page div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are referring to debugging , you can right click , choose inspect element and you will see in the console next to style a tab called "computed" that is all the css loaded on that element, there you can see what font is used. If however a user has the "times" font installed on his system as "Arial" for example you will see it rendering arial but displaying "times" characters.

Comment: Oh, chrome has this feature, that's great.